# can anyone tell me how I can create a branch in tfs under as shown

Tags: tfs

I am new to TFS. Can anyone tell me what the below symbol means 
 and how I can create it.
[image]

Is it a branch ?
When I try to create a branch it creates a folder . I would like it create a branch 
with this symbol . Can anyone help me with this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a branch. There are multiple ways to create one.

Simplest Situation: You have a folder. In the Source Control explorer, right click the folder and from the context menu pick <kbd>Branching and Merging</kbd> and then <kbd>Convert to Branch</kbd>.

The second option is where you have an existing folder and you want to create a child of that branch. Right click the existing branch and again from the <kbd>Branching and Merging</kbd> context menu pick <kbd>Branch...</kbd>. In the dialog that appears, make sure you check the *Immediately convert source folder to branch (enables visualisations)* option.